# Set GameObject From Http Request Result in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, http-post

I have 4 buttons in my project and all these buttons call different score results from server. At awake function I generate a table with random values and it works pretty fine. However when I call a function and get results I couldnt set the table with received values because entryContainer and entryTemplate would be null which I think should not be because they are instantiated!. Here is my code which works pretty fine at page opening but could not set items after receiving request

```
using Assets.Scripts.HttpPost;
using Assets.Scripts.Models;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HighScoreTable : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Transform entryContainer;
    public static Transform entryTemplate;
    public List<HighscoreEntry> highscoreEntryList;
    public static List<Transform> highscoreEntryTransformList;
    public static bool isChanged = false;

    public void Awake()
    {

        // Works pretty fine at opening
        entryContainer = transform.Find("highscoreEmptyContainer");
        entryTemplate = entryContainer.Find("highscoreEntryTemplate");

        entryTemplate.gameObject.SetActive(false);

        highscoreEntryList = new List<HighscoreEntry>() {
            new HighscoreEntry{score = 33.6, username = "Osman"},
            new HighscoreEntry{score = 46033.5, username = "Ahmet"},
            new HighscoreEntry{score = 1833.5, username = "Veli"},
            new HighscoreEntry{score = 563.5, username = "Can"},
            new HighscoreEntry{score = 433.5, username = "Esma"},
            new HighscoreEntry{score = 6533.5, username = "Gözde"},
            new HighscoreEntry{score = 733.5, username = "Ayşe"},
            new HighscoreEntry{score = 733.5, username = "Fatma"},
            new HighscoreEntry{score = 383.5, username = "Hayriye"}
        };
        //generates table its ok 
        highscoreEntryTransformList = new List<Transform>();
        foreach (var highscoreEntry in highscoreEntryList)
        {
            CreateHighscoreEntryTransform(highscoreEntry, entryContainer, highscoreEntryTransformList);
        }
    }

    public void Update()
    {

    }
    private void CreateHighscoreEntryTransform(HighscoreEntry highscoreEntry, Transform container, List<Transform> transformList)
    {
        float templateHeight = 30f;
        while (container == null)
            container = transform.Find("highscoreEmptyContainer");
        Transform entryTransform = Instantiate(entryTemplate, entryContainer);
        RectTransform entryRectTransform = entryTransform.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        entryRectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(0, -30 - templateHeight * transformList.Count);
        entryTransform.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        int rank = transformList.Count + 1;

        string rankString;

        switch (rank)
        {
            default:
                rankString = rank + "TH"; break;
            case 1: rankString = "1ST"; break;
            case 2: rankString = "2ND"; break;
            case 3: rankString = "3RD"; break;
        }
        entryTransform.Find("posText").GetComponent<Text>().text = rankString;
        double score = highscoreEntry.score;
        entryTransform.Find("scoreText").GetComponent<Text>().text = score.ToString();
        entryTransform.Find("nameText").GetComponent<Text>().text = highscoreEntry.username;

        transformList.Add(entryTransform);
    }
    #region AllVerbal
    public WWW AllVerbalGet(string postAddress, string jsonData)
    {
        entryContainer = transform.Find("highscoreEmptyContainer");
        entryTemplate = entryContainer.Find("highscoreEntryTemplate");

        entryTemplate.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        WWW www;
        byte[] formData = null;
        try
        {
            Hashtable postHeader = new Hashtable();
            postHeader.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

            // convert json string to byte
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonData))
            {
                formData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData);
            }
            www = new WWW(postAddress, formData, postHeader);
            StartCoroutine(WaitForAllVerbalGetRequest(www));
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            www = null;
        }
        return www;
    }
    //Wait for the www Request
    IEnumerator WaitForAllVerbalGetRequest(WWW www)
    {
        yield return www;
        if (www.error == null)
        {
            //Print server response
            try
            {
                LeaderboardListModel result = JsonUtility.FromJson<LeaderboardListModel>("{\"leaders\":" + www.text + "}");
                highscoreEntryList = new List<HighscoreEntry>();
                // Items received and converted to model successfully!
                HighscoreEntry temp;
                foreach (var item in result.leaders)
                {
                    temp = new HighscoreEntry();
                    temp.username = item.username;
                    temp.score = item.totalScore;
                    temp.weekscore = item.weeklyTotalScore;
                    highscoreEntryList.Add(temp);
                }
                highscoreEntryTransformList = new List<Transform>();

                foreach (var highscoreEntry in highscoreEntryList)
                {
                    // HERE IS THE PROBLEM ENTRY CONTAINER IS NULL BUT ITS INSTANTIATED AT AWAKE FUNCTION!!!!!!!!!!!
                    // I ALSO TRY TO SET THESE ITEMS AGAIN BUT STILL  RETURNS NULL
                    //entryContainer = transform.Find("highscoreEmptyContainer");
                    //entryTemplate = entryContainer.Find("highscoreEntryTemplate");
                    //entryTemplate.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    //WHAT SHOULD I DO entry container is null!! :(
                    CreateHighscoreEntryTransform(highscoreEntry, entryContainer, highscoreEntryTransformList);
                }
                isChanged = true;

            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                highscoreEntryList = new List<HighscoreEntry>();
                highscoreEntryTransformList = new List<Transform>();
                foreach (var highscoreEntry in highscoreEntryList)
                {
                    CreateHighscoreEntryTransform(highscoreEntry, entryContainer, highscoreEntryTransformList);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {

            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public void allVerbalButton_Click()
    {
        isChanged = true;
        AllVerbalGet(HttpOperations.allVerbalURL, null);
    }

    public void allCompButton_Click()
    {
        isChanged = true;
        AllVerbalGet(HttpOperations.allCompURL, null);
    }

    public void Top10VerbalButton_Click()
    {
        isChanged = true;
        AllVerbalGet(HttpOperations.Top10VerbalURL, null);
    }

    public void Top10ComputButton_Click()
    {
        isChanged = true;
        AllVerbalGet(HttpOperations.Top10CompURL, null);
    }
    [System.Serializable]
    public class HighscoreEntry
    {
        public double score;
        public string username;
        public double weekscore;
    }
}
```

I am pretty new at unity but couldnt solve it :( Any help would be great

Comment: if you do it too early all the components in the game may not have been made yet.  You can change the creation order manually to ensure they are made first

Comment: This `while (container == null)
                container = transform.Find("highscoreEmptyContainer");` would basically freeze your entire application forever in case it fails...

Comment: Instead of all these error prone `Find` calls you should rather use some public Fields and reference them all via the Inspector. Also within the prefab so when you instantiate it it already knows all its inner references!

Comment: derHugo  I paste one of the combinations here yes u re righ it freezes :) and in another combination I referenced it from Unity screen but Im not sure since Im new at unity ay game object can be bind to Transform object.